# Use make_unique/make_shared in member initializer lists or in-class-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, std, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

make_unique/make_shared can throw, so I'm not sure is it ok to call them in  member initializer lists?
And if it's ok is it any difference with using them with () or {}?

```
A::A() : ptr1(std::make_unique<type>()), ptr2{std::make_unique<type>()} {}
```

Is it ok and will be any difference in creating and initialization of ptr1 and ptr2?

UPD: also is it a good idea to use make_unique/make_shared in in-class-initialization?

Comment: It's fine. If they throw, your constructor gets unwound correctly and the exception just propogates out to the calling code as normal. Then only time it would be a problem is if some of your members used dynamically allocated raw pointers or other unmanaged resources that can't be cleaned up automatically.

Comment: No difference here.

Comment: @Useless I see, thanks. And what about  in-class-initialization, probably there it's not ok to use them?

Comment: In-class initialization behaves as if you had written the initialization code in the member initialization list.  It's syntactic sugar.